# Parsing a flash json response (Delphi/ TWebbrowser)

Tags: json, flash, delphi, delphi-xe2, twebbrowser

I have a flash game and get updates after pressing a button. Only a table inside the flash gets updated and the changes are not shown in the html source (well, its flash after all). Logging with Fiddler shows first one encrypted package (containing all data of the table after decoding with Fiddler) followed by 16x json packages (single entry of the table).

What i want to know is how to get those single packages in Delphi.

I do not want to alter the data, i simply want to read them. I cant make any changes to anything (webserver, flash, etc).

Comment: Please edit your answer to tell us your Delphi version. There is DBXJSON in later Delphi versions.

Comment: Progdigy.com has SuperObject package. Might be nice if you make an class representing the message and would fill it from the packet in ORM way.

Comment: My Problem is not to interpret the package (or at least not right now) but to get it in the first way in Delphi.

Comment: then that is question about Internet Explorer and Flash, not about Delphi. Can you register some BHO to intercept HTTP traffic or not. AFAIr that was a way how Fiddler v.1 worked. ReGet Deluxe PErsonal also has MSIE Spy addon implementing this. You should ask Internet Explorer community whether you can intercept Flash AJAX data packets or not. Then with that receipt given you can port it to Delphi and ask about certain problems of porting.  Additionally you may try using Chrome instead of TWebBrowser, it has some special build of Flash, dunno if that would make interception easier or harder.

Comment: you may try implementing some dumb pseudo-proxy in your application. Then ask TWebBrowser to use that proxy (again ask MSIE gurus how you can force proxy onto some certain ActiveX instance) and maybe - just maybe - Flahs plugin would use that proxy too. But probably not, since in Control Panel there is a separate independent setting for flash proxy. Whell, as a very crude ugly solution, you can change flash proxy settings before opening the page and reverting it after page loaded. But that IS ugly.

Comment: Adding to @Arioch's comment, EmbeddedWB (http://www.bsalsa.com) can use a system independent proxy, not sure if it will work for the flash component though

Comment: @whosrdaddy i expect it does not. For what i remember NP API does not export network streaming and i think flash has its own isolated from browser HTTP layer

Answer (score 0):

You could try proxying like Arioch suggested. I'm not too sure it would work, though.

If I were to do it this would be how:

- Create a shared library in C (or C++) where you can hook up various dest/origin addresses and ports using [WinPcap](http://www.winpcap.org/)
- Have it call your application when something get's caught
- Process/manipulate the packet data as needed
- Pass it on

Unfortunately there's no working WinPcap "headers" (or components) for Delphi, so there's no other way (other than porting all the headers to Delphi ...).

[Here's a tutorial on how to use WinPcap](http://www.winpcap.org/docs/docs_41b5/html/group__wpcap__tut.html).